# Where is the implementation of values-list in SBCL?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I am trying to figure out the implementation of `values-list` function in SBCL.
The source code at `src/code/eval.lisp` looks like pretty simple, but why doesn't  it fall into infinite recursion?

```
(defun values-list (list)
  #!+sb-doc
  "Return all of the elements of LIST, in order, as values."
  (values-list list))
```

If I define a function `foo` like that, it will fall into infinite recursion:

```
(defun foo (list)
   (foo list))
```

Comment: `values-list` is handled by the compiler specially - either as a `compiler-macro` or internally. the code you see is never executed directly (because SBCL has no interpreter, all code is always compiled).

Comment: @sds: SBCL has an interpreter. http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Interpreter

Comment: @RainerJoswig: interesting, thanks. this must be a recent development. (What I meant was [By default SBCL implements eval by calling the native code compiler](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Interpreter)).

Comment: @sds: 2015, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

In short, because something else has already taught the compiler how to compile calls to `(values-list)`, so the `(values-list)` referred to in the function body does not to refer to the function being defined.

The reason why that function definition exists at all is a little more tricky. In compiled code which calls the function directly, the compiler can just defer to whatever other bit of code handles compiling calls to that function. However, just because the compiler knows how to compile direct calls to `(values-list)` does not mean it is a function- it could, effectively, be just a special form or macro. That seemingly recursive definition ensures that an actual function object exists, so things like `#'values-list` and calls to the function at the repl (if the repl is set to use the interpreter) work as expected.

In this case, `#'values-list` is implemented using a virtual operation (VOP, something which the compiler can compile directly to machine instructions) on each of SBCL's target platforms, as you can see with a [search through the source](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/search?p=1&q=%20values-list&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Take a look [here](https://www.pvk.ca/Blog/2014/08/16/how-to-define-new-intrinsics-in-sbcl/) if you want to know more about this. In that article, Paul Khoung adds support for SBCL to use the intel x86-64 popcnt instruction to compile calls to a new function `#'popcnt`, and as the last step he defines a function like so

```
(in-package "POPCNT")

(defun popcnt (x) (popcnt x))
```

Which he notes

> isn’t strictly necessary, but helps people who like their REPL. The
>   compiler knows how to compile calls to popcnt, so we can define
>   popcnt… as a call to popcnt. Our new function is now a first-class
>   value that can be called from interpreted code and passed to
>   higher-order functions, like the compiler’s constant-folding pass.

Comment: it seems like far beyond my knowledge, actually I not programmer, but I am interesting in programming :) anyway, much thanks for your details.